# removing and adding classes to modal content elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 `modal` elements. In *both* I have this little **javascript styling element**: https://jsfiddle.net/EricTalv/wjmfe799/10/
By only having one of these on **one page** it works *fine*.

**The problem** comes when I try to add these to my modals: 
https://jsfiddle.net/EricTalv/x5qwnv82/1/

So, when I **already** have a class `.active` in the DOM the *first modal* works well,  **however**, the second one doesn't function at all, and after I leave the first modal and come back, the previously selected item seems to stay there which is a nice addition but I feel like this seems to be causing problems as well.

**What I want to do** is to add an `.active` class **only** when one of those items is pressed, and upon leaving the last chosen item should stay.

**I tried** this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/pb95kv32/
this concept could work but couldn't really get it to work, but also makes it harder to read so a more efficient solution would be great.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- The Modal 1-->
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading 11111</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div id="list-area">
        <ul id="list-items-container">
          <li class="item">item1</li>
          <li class="item">item2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal 2-->
<div class="modal" id="modal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading 22222</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div id="list-area">
        <ul id="list-items-container">
          <li class="item active">other1</li>
          <li class="item">other2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var header = document.getElementById("list-items-container");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

/* the list area  */

#list-area {
  background-color: #FC600A;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 50%;
}

#list-items-container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#list-items-container li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Corbel;
  color: #1489B8;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#list-items-container li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #F7E0D4;
}

#list-items-container li:hover,
#list-items-container .active {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can only one item be selected at the same time or can multiple have an `active` class added from each modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can not have duplicated ids. So I've changed `#list-area` to
   `.list-area` and `#list-items-container` to `.list-items-container` in html and css code.
2. JS changes:

   ```
   //Get all buttons
   var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

   for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
     btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

         //for clicked item getting parentNode and all its child
         var siblings = this.parentNode.childNodes

         //check if children have class "active" and remove it
         siblings.forEach(function(element) {
             if (element.className && element.className.indexOf('active') !== -1) {
                 element.classList.remove("active");
             }
         })
         //set 'active' to clicked element
         this.className += " active";
     });
   }
   ```

Here is working updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tehLj8b5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You are using two "id" attributes with the same value (`<ul id="list-items-container"></ul>`). In an HTML page you are allowed to use only unique IDs, that is your problem!

```js
var header = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.list-items-container'));

header.forEach(function(hd) {
  var bts = [].slice.call(hd.querySelectorAll('.item'));
  
  bts.forEach(function(bt) {
    bt.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var current = document.querySelector('.item.active');
      current.className = current.className.replace(' active', '');
      this.className += ' active';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

/* the list area  */

.list-area {
  background-color: #FC600A;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.list-items-container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-items-container li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Corbel;
  color: #1489B8;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.list-items-container li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #F7E0D4;
}

.list-items-container li:hover,
.list-items-container .active {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">
    Open modal 1
  </button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">
    Open modal 2
  </button>


<!-- The Modal 1-->
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading 11111</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div class="list-area">
        <ul class="list-items-container">
          <li class="item">item1</li>
          <li class="item">item2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal 2-->
<div class="modal" id="modal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading 22222</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div class="list-area">
        <ul class="list-items-container">
          <li class="item active">other1</li>
          <li class="item">other2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could swap you JavaScript out for this nifty little bit of jQuery. Here it'll toggle the class of `active` on whatever `li` element is clicked and remove it from it's siblings:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```